# Is there an ESLint pre-made config file for IE8/IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, eslint

I'm trying to validate some code already written code for older browsers, but I don't want to have to build my own config and potentially miss some obvious rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use eslint-puglin-compat it uses caniuse.com to provide information on browser compatibility

you can define what browsers to target

```
// Simple configuration (package.json)
{
  // ...
  "browserslist": ["last 1 versions", "not ie <= 8"],
}
```

https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat